# How to install AdoptOpenJDK 8 and 11 parallel to Oracle JDK 8 and use both with Eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, eclipse, adoptopenjdk

I'm trying to update Java to Version 11, but don't want to use Oracles JDK because of the license. I also would like to install and use AdoptOpenJDK 8 because of that. My OS is Windows 10.

I've already tried to install AdoptOpenJDK 11 without overwriting any settings, as I want other java-programs to still run using Oracles JRE 8. I added the AdoptOpenJDK installation folder to the installed JREs in eclipse and when I ran some test code, "java.version" was set to 11.0.7, but when trying the new 'var' feature, Eclipse said that `'var' is not allowed here`. I changed the compiler compliance level to 11 and updated to Eclipse Version 2020-03 (4.15.0), but it still didn't work.
Then I reinstalled AdoptOpenJDK 11 and let the installer change all the settings, but it still wouldn't work.

How can I install AdoptOpenJDK 8 and 11 parallel to OracleJDK 8 on my system and set in Eclipse which one to use per project?

EDIT: Ok, it works now, apparently I just didn't understand how to use 'var' correctly. Thank you for your help nonetheless.

Comment: Did you set the compiler compliance level via the _Properties_ item in the _Project_ menu, or via the _Preferences_ item in the _Window_ menu? You need to do it via the _Project > Properties_.

Comment: All JDKs/JREs must be configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ to be able to use them in projects and in launch configurations.

Comment: First I set the compiler compliance level in the _Window_ menu, but I tried it again in the _Project > Properties_ and it still wouldn't work.
The JDK is configured in _Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs_. I added it by clicking _Add > Standard VM > Next_ and set the jre home to the AdoptOpenJDK installation path (`AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.7.10-hotspot`).

Answer (score 0):

The error message `'var' is not allowed here` means that you are using Java 10 or higher, but **`var`** is used **somewhere** in the code **where you cannot**.  Otherwise, for a compiler compliance level lower than 10, you would get `var cannot be resolved to a type`.

Example:

```
class Sample {

    var s = ""; // 'var' is not allowed here

    var foo() { // 'var' is not allowed here
        // ...
    }

    void foo(var x) { // 'var' is not allowed here
        // ...

        var s = ""; // okay

    }

}
```